# Berkeley Min Wage: what if you are only required to do 5 minutes of work?

Tags: contract-law, employment, california, contractor

Berkeley has a minimum wage law but it is set to 18.07 per hour. How does this work if work is divided into minutes?

Separately, does 18.07 per hour comprise 18.07 minimum per day?

Also, what are the differences if the employer is not officially classified as "employer"?

Comment: Have you read the law?  Also is the five minutes the agreed scope of the work or is it a case of showing up for a longer scheduled shift and the employer releasing the employee early?

Comment: @phoog, "the law" meaning? Showing up to work at any time (either chosen by employee or by employer or both) for say 5 minutes.

Comment: Meaning [the appropriate sections of the Berkeley Municipal Codes.](https://berkeley.municipal.codes/BMC/13.99)  Note that for the minimum wage law to apply, the employee must work a minimum of 2 hours per calendar week.

Comment: Also, [this article about rounding policies for hours worked](https://www.worklawyers.com/rounding-hours-worked/) seems to be pertinent.

Comment: People are paid for the time they work, 5 minutes is 1/12 of an hour, which would net you $1.51, but I have literally never heard of paying people to work for 5 minutes.  The law doesn't apply to the employer if it doesn't apply to the employer, as defined in the Berkeley Municipal Code.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, for 1st link, the definition if based on hours would be circular yes, but of course for the purposes of q just assume it is asking about the market / or judge has/will decide he is treated as  employee. For 2nd link, employer has not established any policy (until work has all been performed / until sued for payment).   @ Tiger, yea but "*even small amounts of daily time*" must be paid, per Michael's 2nd link. It makes no sense that work can be free.

Comment: there are at times laws or contracts that dictate a minimum time per shift. It's actually rather typical for IT contractors. Things like "show up, clock in, press the server reset button, clock out, go home" - like literally 60 seconds of work - might be treated as 2 hours of work, maybe even with gas money just for showing up.

Comment: @Pacerier The legal standard concerning partial hours is outlined in the second article: the employer may not round off partial hours worked in such a way that an employee is systematically undercompensated.  [See 29 C.F.R. §785.48(b).](https://casetext.com/regulation/code-of-federal-regulations/title-29-labor/subtitle-b-regulations-relating-to-labor/chapter-v-wage-and-hour-division-department-of-labor/subchapter-b-statements-of-general-policy-or-interpretation-not-directly-related-to-regulations/part-785-hours-worked/subpart-d-recording-working-time/section-78548-use-of-time-clocks) ...

Comment: ... But whether a particular employer's practices led to undercompensation is something that would have to be decided by a court.  I would think that if an employer didn't have an explicit "rounding policy" written down, it would weaken their case if they were sued, since an employee could argue that their rounding practices were arbitrary. OTOH, it would also matter if the employee actually *was* undercompensated in practice. For example, if the employee was paid for a quarter-hour every time they worked 5 minutes, the employee wouldn't have much of a case.

Comment: [All of this is in comments because (a) I'm not an expert in labor law and (b) I suspect the answer is effectively "there's no clear rule about it, just a general principle."]

Comment: @Trish, 2 hours!?? which laws  dictate a minimum time per shift? ("contracts" don't count since this q obviously assumes it's unstated.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, "was paid for a quarter-hour"; The q obviously assumes the employee was paid just 5 minutes (or 5.1 minutes), hence a q.

Comment: It seems like there was more than one "obvious" aspect of the situation that was not explicitly stated in the question.  You can, of course, [edit] your question to make these assumptions explicit.